# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with a mouse emulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, byte

I have this python2.7 script which works fine on a "Raspberry Pi Zero W" to emulate a mouse on a desktop pc to move the mouse 127 pixels to north-west.

```
report = '\x00\x81\x81\x00'
with open('/dev/hidg1', 'rb+') as fd:
    fd.write(report)
```

Now, I tried it with python3 an I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    fd.write(report)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I found some solutions with `fd.write(report.encode())` but this submits something different to the desktop pc. Not just a move of the mouse. It moves (not 127 pixels) and makes a right click with the mouse. This is not what I want.

Comment: I guess you should pass it a [`bytes` object](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3) which is not the same thing as a `str`.

Comment: @pault They are open a device handle (for a mouse) and passing binary commands to it, so `rb+` is indeed appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try - converting `report` to a bytes object.

```
report = b'\x00\x81\x81\x00'
```

This differs from the previous solution you tried -

```
>>> '\x00\x81\x81\x00'.encode()
b'\x00\xc2\x81\xc2\x81\x00'
```